# @Version annotation on MongoTemplate entity model

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Sometimes I get strange `OptimisticLockingException`. Surfing the internet and I found it's kind of relevant to the `@Version` annotation. I tried to remove the following fields from the base model class:

```
@Version
private Long version;
```

A smoke test shows nothing is wrong with the system. However I would like to know if there is any problems without declaring the version field in a mongo model class?

Thanks,
Green

Answer (score 2):

You may be having some concurrency issues. That exception is thrown when concurrent changes to the same entity are being made and the second changes gets notified that the entity was just updated by someone else. 
In fact, the version annotation applies to a field that is incremented after every entity update. If you are trying to update an entity, but someone else has just committed a change to the same entity, then you get the exception.
By removing the @Version annotation, you just don't have a version field, so the issue does not arise, but changes are still happening to the entity in a way that might be inappropriate (i.e. not regulated).